# Parse Facebook token from URL which is after #

Tags: php, facebook

I have PHP script and Facebook application registred but application will redirect user to mypage.com/fblogin.php#access_token=FacebookToken

How can I get access token ? I've tryed $_GET["access_token"] and also POST, but it didn't work.

Comment: You can change the way Facebook gives you these tokens, in the settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't access URL anchors server-side. You'd have to use javascript to form a request that sends it in a query string or post.

Comment: Can you please give me example ?

Comment: You can just split off the hash tag, e.g., 
`var anchor = document.location.toString().split("#")[1];` If the url is `http://example.com/page.php/#!123` then the `anchor` variable will contain `!123`. You'll want to put more defense into this code but it shows the general approach. You can then redirect or use AJAX to send that data to your server-side script.